# how to allow multiple possible interfaces as a parameter type in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to allow multiple possible interfaces as the parameter and I am using a union of them but it hasn't worked.

```
interface A {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}

interface B {
  index: number;
  method1: () => void;
}

type AnyType = A | B;


const Components: Record<number, (args: AnyType) => JSX.Element> = {
  1: Component1,
  2: Component2,
};
```

An error is highlighted over the `1` above:

```
Type 'AnyType' is not assignable to type 'A'.
      Type 'B' is missing the following properties from type 'A': name, value
```

I have also tried 'overloading' the entire function type:

```
type AnyType = {
  (args: A): JSX.Element;
  (args: B): JSX.Element;
};
```

but it has returned the same error.

The reason i think is that types don't handle the children of interfaces.

What is the best way to string together being able to use multiple different interfaces as a parameter type?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html - have tried optional properties on the interfaces to see if that helps using the question mark?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NVg1lm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.